# Утечка оперативной памяти в sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3, асинхронность

Создал асинхронного бота на **aiogram**. Появилась утечка **ОЗУ**. Предполагаю что проблема в этом, но у меня не достаточно знаний о **sqlite3**:
Мои объекты базы данных являются **глобальными** переменными. И с помощью них функции читают/записывают данные **БД**.

```
connect = sqlite3.connect(bd_name,check_same_thread=False)
cursor = connect.cursor()
```

Утечка могла появится из-за подобных глобальных переменных?
Лучше каждый раз заново инициализировать подключение к **БД** в каждой функции в качестве локальных переменных, чем использовать мой способ?

Comment: я не знаю ответа на вопрос, но я бы с помощью принтов посмотрел какие данные хранятся и записываются в эти переменные в процессе работы программы. Если они накапливаются а не перезаписываюься, то лучше делать их локальными, а если нет, то проблема видимо в другом

Comment: почему вы решили что проблема именно в sqlite? мне кажется это маловероятно и проблема где-то еще. нужно дебажить - есть [неплохая статья на английском](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316152429/http://www.lshift.net/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks/)